# Using x86 or x64 library in metro style app for ARM platform

Tags: microsoft-metro, c++-cx

I want to use an older C++ library in a metro app.
I can build this library either as x86 or x64.
Basically what I was thinking to do was to write a C++/CX wrapper for this library.

However in Visual Studio I see that the available platforms for my wrapper project are: Win32, ARM and x64.
I'm guessing it will work just fine with the Win32 and x64 platforms, but will I be able to use the library when I build for the ARM platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to be able to build the library for ARM if you want it to run on an ARM processor. ARM doesn't understand x86.